search this site option is not working SharePoint 2010
We are unable to track reason behind non-working of search this site option is not working SharePoint 2010.
Enterprise search is working but site search is not working.

no it is not working

So why create two questions with the same issue?

This is different question i have an error in Search Site inside any document library / Site collection is not working.

So the first issue is resolved? You need to update it to explain the root cause. Keep it simple, one issue at a time.
